# POST data through socket.io to app.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I would like to:

- retrieve data entered from input forms.
- send the data through socket.io and send console log saying done
- receive the data on express app.js
- insert the data into a mongodb database using mongoose.

I understand emit messages but not sure how to post data through. thank you in advance

my app.js is set up like this:

```
//app.js config ...

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('socket.io connected');
});



app.post('/go', function(req, res) {

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    new Order({
      routeFrom : data.routeFrom,
      routeTo : data.routeTo,
      leaving: data.leaving
    }).save(function(err, docs) {
      if(err) { console.log("error"); }
      res.json(data);
    });
    socket.emit('callback', {done: 'Done'});
  });

});
```

my index.ejs file:

```
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

$('#send').on('click', function() {
    $.post('/go', {
       socket.emit('data', {
        routeFrom: $('#rf').val(),
        routeTo: $('#rt').val(),
        leaving: $('#l').val()
       });

    });

  socket.on('callback', function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  });

});
```

Comment: This seems a little confused. Why do you want to receive the data throuch socket.io and then "route" it through express? I think it would be wise to make a choice: either just post the form (and perhaps send a notification back through the socket) or send the data over the socket to persist it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need `POST` at all.

I would do on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

$('#send').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('data', {
    routeFrom: $('#rf').val(),
    routeTo: $('#rt').val(),
    leaving: $('#l').val()
  });
});

socket.on('callback', function(data) {
  console.log(data.done);
  // Print the data.data somewhere...
});
```

And on the server side:

```
//app.js config ...
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('socket.io connected');
});

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  new Order({
    routeFrom : data.routeFrom,
    routeTo : data.routeTo,
    leaving: data.leaving
  }).save(function(err, docs) {
    if(err) { return console.log("error"); }
    socket.emit('callback', {done: 'Done', data: data});
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you! one more thing, in response, it returns: "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Comment: Oh yeah my bad. I edited my answer. You need to send the data back through socket.io instead of express (`res.json(...)`). I added `data: data` in the `socket.emit('callback'...)`. Then you need to print the data on the client side.